# Are there any regular coding challenges hosted on Stack Overflow for AngularJS?

Tags: support

I am new to Stack Overflow. I was wondering if there is any place here where  coding challenges are posted on a regular basis?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, so you won't find any code challenges here. You might find some on [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) but as the help section you were shown when you registered explains that would be wildly off topic on SO.

Comment: Yes, tons of them. Look for new questions with the [tag:angular] tag.

Comment: See also on MSE: [How do weekly topic challenges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634)

Comment: You may find some of the questions on [CodeReview.se] interesting. And [CodeGolf.se] comes to mind, but there's not much about AngularJS there.

Comment: To be clear: We don't do weekly topic challenges on Stack Overflow, @Pang. We get plenty of questions, without taking steps to encourage additional ones.

Answer (score 14):

No. Stack Overflow is not a place where coding challenges are appropriate.

On the Stack Exchange network, we do have [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), which hosts a variety of programming puzzles that can be answered in any language.